# Errno 13 Permission denied: while loading csv files and plotting a gaussian fit

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, gaussian, permission-denied

I am getting an error while storing the contents of a csv file into an array. My csv files consists of 2 columns of x-values and y-values. I am using a for loop to loop through a folder of csv files, obtain their file names and store the contents of columns in an array. My first column needs to be stored in xData[] and my second column in yData[].
I am able to print the file names of all the csv files in the folder.
However, I am struggling to find the logic in adding the contents of files into an array.

I am getting

> Errno 3: Permission denied error.

I also think there is a problem in my while loop.

Once I get the 2 arrays, I want to plot the values of xData against yData and fit a Gaussian into my data.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import asarray as ar,exp
import lmfit
from glob import glob 
import os
from lmfit import Parameters, minimize, report_fit, Model 
import glob
path=r'E:\Users\ConfocalUser\Documents\GitHub\qudi'
location=glob.glob(path+'/*.csv')
###check if the path is correct
xData=[]
yData=[]
While location=True:
with open(path,"r") as f_in:
    reader=csv.reader(f_in)
    next(reader)
    
    for line in reader:
        try:
            float_1,float_2=float(line[0]),float(line[1])
            xData.append(float_1)
            yData.append(float_2)
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

Comment: If you get a permission denied when accessing a file, this does not depend on how you intend to process the content. It just means you do not have permissions to access the file. Change the permissions of the file to match what you are trying to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to use `pandas.read_csv` function (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#csv-text-files) to get your csv file directly into a dataframe that you can use to plot the data (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/intro_tutorials/04_plotting.html). Something along the lines of this:

```
dataframes = []
for filepath in glob.iglob(path + "/*.csv"):
    dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(filepath))
df = pd.concat(dataframes)
# Let's say your csv looks like this:
# "a","b"
# 1,2
# 2,3
# 3,4
# And you want your x data to be the "a" column and y to be "b"
df.plot.scatter(x="a", y="b")
```

Comment: How shall I store the x-column and y-columns? Could you please say what to include in the place of  "your x column" in 'x="your x column" and y="your y column"

Comment: it depends on the content of your csv files. Look at their header row and identify which header you would like to have as x and which one you would like to have as y. Then "your x column" shall be the name of the header for x as it appears in the csv and "your y column" shall be the name of the header for y as it appears in the csv. eg: your csv is like this:
    "a","b"
    1,2
    2,3
And you want x to be a and y to be b. Then you would have:
    df.plot.scatter(x="a", y="b")

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect how to get x and y in the `df.plot.scatter` snippet